# [Amazon][JDSI](20320) Data type not supported in Talend

Tags: talend

Exception in component tRedshiftOutput_2
java.sql.SQLDataException: [Amazon]JDSI Data type not supported: 1111
    at com.amazon.redshift.api.PGDataTypeUtilities.createTypeMetadata(PGDataTypeUtilities.java:855)
    at com.amazon.redshift.api.PGDataTypeUtilities.createParameter(PGDataTypeUtilities.java:2049)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.prepareStatement(PGClient.java:1856)
    at com.amazon.redshift.dataengine.PGQueryExecutor.(PGQueryExecutor.java:106)
    at com.amazon.redshift.dataengine.PGDataEngine.prepare(PGDataEngine.java:211)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.jdbc41.S41PreparedStatement.(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.jdbc41.PGJDBC41PreparedStatement.(PGJDBC41PreparedStatement.java:49)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.jdbc41.PGJDBC41ObjectFactory.createPreparedStatement(PGJDBC41ObjectFactory.java:119)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at tsdwh.jb0203_0_1.JB0203.tRedshiftInput_2Process(JB0203.java:3389)
    at tsdwh.jb0203_0_1.JB0203.runJobInTOS(JB0203.java:7195)
Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.DataException: [Amazon]JDSI Data type not supported: 1111
    ... 12 more
I can't convert date to timestamp to Talend, cant i have you ?

Comment: Can you show us the code that results in the error?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't convert date to timestamp to Talend, cant i have you ?

If you are trying to convert date into timestamp, there is no need to convert that. Just choose `Date` as the data type and set the `DB Type` to `TIMESTAMP` in the schema of your `tRedshiftOutput` component. Talend will automatically convert from `Date` to `Timestamp`.

See also here for some hints on how to convert and format between dates:
https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4629

Comment: i can't convert,I followed the instructions above

Comment: TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",context.myDate)

but

Execution failed : Job compile errors 
At least job "JB0203" has a compile errors, please fix and export again.
Error Line: 4566
Detail Message: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Date
There may be some other errors caused by JVM compatibility. Make sure your JVM setup is similar to the studio.

Comment: Can you give me specific examples?

Comment: That's probably because the routine `formatDate`, expects a `String` and a `Date`, but your context variable `myDate` is a `String`. (see here for the javadoc of those libraries: https://extras.gabrielebaldassarre.com/tos5-4/d5/de4/classroutines_1_1_talend_date.html#aef7100548b6c0049a2681fbed0ea6b1b). If that's the case you can either 1) change your context variable to the `Date` type or 2) use the `parseDate` routine which takes `String` as a parameter for both parameters (see the javadoc I linked earlier).